# Efficient way to aggregate on dates in pandas groupby

Tags: python, pandas, aggregate

When performing a groupby on dates (as `object`), I realized it was way less efficient than on `int`. Here is an example:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'id1':[1,1,1,1,2,2,2,3,3,3],'id2':[10,20,30,10,20,30,10,20,30,10],'value':[123,156,178,19,354,26,84,56,984,12],
                   'date':['2015-01-12','2014-09-27','2014-10-14','2010-11-26','2010-04-09','2012-12-21','2009-08-16',
                          '2013-07-09','2014-02-14','2012-12-04']})
df

Out[1]:
    date        id1 id2 value
0   2015-01-12  1   10  123
1   2014-15-27  1   20  156
2   2014-10-14  1   30  178
3   2010-11-26  1   10  19
4   2010-04-09  2   20  354
5   2012-12-21  2   30  26
6   2009-08-16  2   10  84
7   2013-07-09  3   20  56
8   2014-02-14  3   30  984
9   2012-12-04  3   10  12
```

Here are the types of the column:

```
df.dtypes

Out[2]:
date     object
id1       int64
id2       int64
value     int64
dtype: object
```

And now let's take a look at the efficiency of aggregations::

```
%timeit df.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg({'value':np.sum})
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.35 ms per loop

%timeit df.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg({'date':np.max})
100 loops, best of 3: 2.75 ms per loop
```

As you can see, it is twice as long for `date` as it is for `value`, which is inconvenient an big dataframes.

Is there a way to perform the `agg` more efficiently on dates? Maybe by changing the type of `date` column, or by using another function the get the max?

Comment: normally dates should be `datetime` but I note that `2014-15-27` is not a valid date unless you're using some funky calendar

Comment: Indeed, I typed it thinking about my 13th, 14th and maybe 15th month apparently! Changed it. (Note that the type of `date` column is still `object`, I suspect this is the problem since `python` can't use dedicated functions for `objects`)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Changing the dtype to `datetime` gives comparable perf for me:

```
In [86]:
df['date'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date'], format='%Y-%m-%d')
df

Out[86]:
        date  id1  id2  value
0 2015-01-12    1   10    123
1 2014-09-27    1   20    156
2 2014-10-14    1   30    178
3 2010-11-26    1   10     19
4 2010-04-09    2   20    354
5 2012-12-21    2   30     26
6 2009-08-16    2   10     84
7 2013-07-09    3   20     56
8 2014-02-14    3   30    984
9 2012-12-04    3   10     12

In [88]:
# with datetime dtype    
%timeit df.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg({'value':np.sum})
%timeit df.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg({'date':np.max})
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 ms per loop
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.33 ms per loop

In [91]:
# with `str` dtype    
%timeit df.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg({'value':np.sum})
%timeit df.groupby(['id1','id2']).agg({'date':np.max})
1000 loops, best of 3: 1.56 ms per loop
100 loops, best of 3: 3.07 ms per loop
```

So with a `datetime` dtype the `agg` performance is comparable to `'value'` column aggregation performance.

Comment: Ok, so the idea indeed was to change the type of the column. I admit being a bit confused about the different formats of `date` in python, I will have to have a look at them. Thank you!

Comment: There is a handy website that explains the `strftime` format fields: http://strftime.org/

Comment: Why is `agg()` actually needed? When I use `df.groupby(['id1','id2']).sum()`, I get the identical result.

Comment: @Cleb I'm assuming that this is just an example bit of code, the OP is likely to be using `agg` with a real list or dict of funcs in their real code or using `agg` out of habit

Comment: Ok, makes sense; was just wondering whether I miss something here.

Comment: @EdChum Well not exactly, in my actual code, I use sum, it was just for the clarity of the question (didn't want the difference between `agg` and `sum` to be raised).
By the way, to change the type of the column, `df['date'].astype('datetime64[ns]')` seems to be more efficient.

Comment: yes but check whether it's done the conversion correctly, also there is trade off in performance between the np funcs and the pandas ones here, the pandas `to_datetime` has more type checking and args support, if your data had erroneous/missing data then `astype` will probably barf whilst `to_datetime` will be able to handle this